# Need help to find values in arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datatable, array-formulas

i need help to find the "Temperature min record (°C)" between the 3 months in the cell G3 based on the name of the city in F3.
Any ideas?

The image below show my sheet

[image]

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: You need `SCAN()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using functions like <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> instead of using <kbd>volatile</kbd> functions like <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> & <kbd>INDIRECT( )</kbd> .

### A Friendly Suggestion

> <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> is a flexible function and it can point to a
> different-sized range that is calculated on-the-fly. But it is a
> **volatile** function. If you go to a completely unrelated cell and enter a number, all of the <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> functions will
> calculate—even if that cell has nothing to do with.
>
> It has been found, Excel is very careful to spend time calculating the
> cells that needs to be calculated. But once you use the
> <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd>, all of the <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> cells, plus
> everything downline from the <kbd>OFFSET()</kbd>, starts calculating
> after every change in the worksheet.
>
> **Why it matters ?** <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> is **not volatile**. You enjoy all of the flexible goodness of <kbd>OFFSET( )</kbd> without the
> time-sucking recalculations over and over.

---

Here is a screenshot showing the formula used:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=MIN(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)+6,))
```

---

The above formula refers the **City** and moves <kbd>6</kbd> rows down to get the desired values.

---

• But if you want to make it more dynamic, i.e. if you want to change the Temperature labels then. (Caveat - Change the function <kbd>MIN( )</kbd> or <kbd>MAX( )</kbd> as per requirements)

```
=MIN(INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)+MATCH(G2,A:A,0)-1,))
```

---

A .Gif

[image]

---

One more alternative approach, i think this is proper:

```
=LET(
     a,INDEX(B:D,MATCH(F3,A:A,0)+MATCH($G$2,A:A,0)-1,),
     SWITCH(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER($G$2," ")," "),"max",MAX(a),"min",MIN(a),a))
```

---

The above formula also works as per your requirement, if you change the temperature labels it will work, but note that, since I am not sure what you want to do with the one written as <kbd>--Temperature ave. (°C)--</kbd> for this the output will spill right, if you have any specific requirement for that temperature, just wrap the desired function like we did for <kbd>MIN( )</kbd> and <kbd>MAX( )</kbd>.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the entries in column A is fixed (as shown in the photo), then you can use the formula:

```vb
=MIN(OFFSET(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(F3;A:A;0));6;1;1;3))
```

and a simpler version without INDIRECT. (I set the -1+6 instead of 5, for explanation of logic)

```vb
=MIN(OFFSET(A1;MATCH(F3;A:A;0)-1+6;1;1;3))
```